# Is it possible to fill in null fields if the correct values exist within other records in the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently there is a particular field in my data set where some of the records have no values; the field is allowed to be NULL in the schema.

Sometimes, however, this data is populated in other records in the database based on the ID.

I would like to run a query to update these NULL fields with the appropriate values based on the contents of the rest of the database.  Assume that there will never be conflicting values for these fields.

For example:

```
ID      Identifier          Address                    Name            OrderID
123                         23 Sheppard Court          David           465464322
456     100100100100        29 Milestone Cres          Terry           651654986
789     200200200200        102 Dynamo Drive           Joseph          397431357
123     300300300300        23 Sheppard Court          David           516198532
```

The records in the above example are unique, but the Identifier field is not populated for the first row.

I would like to run a query that would allow me to quickly update this missing field with the correct value, i.e. 300300300300 in this case.

Comment: Does your table have a PK?

Comment: Can you expand on the logic for how we would know the Identifier. Are there only 3 IDs which always map to the same 3 identifiers or is there more to it than this?

Comment: I am going to vote this down as an example of bad design asking for band-aid.

Comment: I didn't design the schema.  Even worse, I don't have access to it to make the necessary corrections.

Answer (score 1):

> Assume that there will never be conflicting values for these fields.

If this is a valid assumption, then this is by far the simplest solution (assuming "ID" is the primary key you are planning to use to backfill values on):

```
UPDATE tableName a
SET identifier = (
    SELECT distinct identifier
    FROM tableName b
    WHERE a.id = b.id
    AND identifier IS NOT NULL)
WHERE identifier IS NULL
```

You can get fancier with `MERGE INTO` syntax, but I'm not sure if that's available in access.

Answer (score 0):

Updates all your missing identifiers.

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET t1.Identifier = 
(SELECT TOP 1 Identifier FROM yourTable 
WHERE t1.Identifier IS NOT NULL)
WHERE t1.Identifier IS NULL
```

**Sidenote:** 
How is it possible that you have such messy data?
Usually you should **never** have to launch such updates on your database.

Also, do you have a Primary Key in your table? Because I can't see one and it's really a **must** on almost any table.